# In C++, why isn't it possible to friend a template class member function using the template type of another class?

Tags: c++, templates, friend

In other words, why does this compile fine :

```
template<typename Type>
class A{
  public:
    void f();
};

class B{
  friend void A<int>::f();
};

template<>
void A<int>::f(){
  B* var = new B();
}
```

While this doesn't :

```
template<typename Type>
class A{
  public:
    void f();
};

template<typename Type> // B is now a templated class
class B{
  friend void A<Type>::f(); // Friending is done using B templated type
};

template<>
void A<int>::f(){
  B<int>* var = new B<int>(); // var is now declared using int as its templated type
}
```

For the second code snippet, compiler (gcc 6.2, no special flags) says:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class B<int>’:
main.cpp:14:28:   required from here
main.cpp:9:15: error: prototype for ‘void A<int>::f()’ does not match any in class ‘A<int>’
   friend void A<Type>::f();
               ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:13:6: error: candidate is: void A<Type>::f() [with Type = int]
 void A<int>::f(){
```

As I understand it, in the second code snippet, when declaring var the compiler should parse B class declaration, replace the Type used in the friend declaration by int, and everything should work fine. What am I missing?

EDIT : comments below have pointed out that the second code snippet seems to compile correctly with clang and Visual C++ 2015

Comment: just FYI. it seems to compile in with clang

Comment: It also compiles with Visual C++ 2015 as you can try here: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

Comment: Works for both clang 3.8 and gcc 6.1.0 [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14434a24d4688733)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An explicit instantiation of `B<int>` before it is used in `A<int>::f()` resolves this problem. I assume GCC tries an implicit instantiation of `B<int>` in the definition of `A<int>::f()`. But the definition of `A<int>::f()` is not finished and GCC 'looses' the friend declaration. It looks like a compiler problem.

```
template<typename Type>
class A
{
public:
    void f();
};

template<typename Type> // B is now a templated class
class B
{
    friend void A<Type>::f(); // Friending is done using B templated type
};

template
class B<int>; // <= explicit instantiation, that works

template<>
void A<int>::f()
{
    B<int>* var = new B<int>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specializing `template class` member function without specializing whole `template class` is special case when you are allowed to specialize non-`template` member function, so maybe `GCC` is confused, and I don't know the reasons, but somehow you can't declare friendship to specialized non-`template` member of `template class`. Temporary solution would be to specialize whole `class template` for this to work.

```
//class template A
template<typename Type>
class A{
  public:
    void f();
};

//class A<int>
template<>
class A<int>{
  public:
    void f();
};
```

Then, define `A<int>::f`:

For `class B:`

```
void A<int>::f(){
      B* var = new B();
      (void)(var);
}
```

For `template class B`:

```
void A<int>::f(){
      B<int>* var = new B<int>();
      (void)(var);
}
```

But I think `Clang` is right here, there should be no problems for such friend declaration. It's probably a bug in `GCC`.