# Class A member template function declared as friend in class B can't access private members of class A (Clang only)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, clang++

Please take a look to this code snippet. I know it does not make much sense, it is just intended to illustrate the problem I am encountering:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct tBar
{
    template <typename T>
    void PrintDataAndAddress(const T& thing)
    {
        cout << thing.mData;
        PrintAddress<T>(thing);
    }

private:
    // friend struct tFoo; // fixes the compilation error

    template <typename T>
    void PrintAddress(const T& thing)
    {
        cout << " - " << &thing << endl;
    }
};

struct tFoo
{
    friend void tBar::PrintDataAndAddress<tFoo>(const tFoo&);
    private:

    int mData = 42;
};

struct tWidget
{
    int mData = 666;
};

int main() 
{
    tBar bar;
    bar.PrintDataAndAddress(tWidget()); // Fine

    bar.PrintDataAndAddress(tFoo()); // Compilation error

    return 0;
}
```

The code above triggers the following error:

> source_file.cpp:10:3: **error: 'PrintAddress' is a private member of 'tBar'
>                  PrintAddress(thing)**;
>   source_file.cpp:42:6: note: in instantiation of function template >specialization 'tBar::PrintDataAndAddress' requested here
>          bar.PrintDataAndAddress(tFoo()); // Compilation error
>   source_file.cpp:17:7: note: declared private here
>          void PrintAddress(const T& thing)

but only in Clang++. GCC and MSVC are fine with it (you can quickly test that by pasting that code in http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_clang)

It seems as if `tBar::PrintDataAndAddress<tFoo>(const tFoo&)` is using the same access as `tFoo`, where it is befriended. I know this because befriending `tFoo` in `tBar` fixes this issue. The problem also goes away if `tBar::PrintDataAndAddress` is a non-template function.

I have not been able to find anything in the Standard that explains this behavior. I believe it could be a bad interpretation of 14.6.5 - temp.inject, but I can't claim I have read all of it.

Does anyone know if Clang is right failing to compile the above code? Can you please quote the relevant C++ standard text if that is the case?

It seems that for this problem to happen, the private member being accessed needs to be a template function. e.g., in the example above, if 
we make PrintAddress a non-template function, the code will compile without errors.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to me completely sensible that clang does not compile this. What I find strange is that the friend declaration commented out, causes this to compile. It seems to me like it should not compile regardless. I've encountered quite a few cases in the past where gcc has "too-lenient" bugs with regards to friendship where a lot of templating is involved, I think that's the case here.

Comment: @NirFriedman why do you think it is sensible that Clang does not compile that? It seems counter-intuitive to me. class A gives friend access to a class B member function (template function in this case) so it has access to A's private and protected members, but why would that remove access to B's private/protected members?

Comment: Looks like a clang bug to me.  Searching to see if it's already reported.

Comment: @NirFriedman: If I understand the OP correctly, `void PrintAddress(const tBar& thing)` compiles (with a suitable adjustment to the friendship of course).  Why is that?

Comment: I suggest raising it as a Clang bug.  You'll probably get an explanation of why it isn't a bug (if it isn't).

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code, I thought you were calling `PrintAddress` directly in the second line of main.

Comment: A trimmed down version: http://rextester.com/YBBQ69572

Comment: Also note in that trimmed down version, *removing* the friend declaration avoids the bug, which is insane.

Comment: @MartinBonner I don't have a llvm bugzilla account (just requested one), so I can't report one. In the meanwhile, if anyone with an account wants to report it, please go ahead and comment on this question with the response

Comment: Still breaks on trunk. Reported as https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=30859 with a slightly shortened version of @aschepler's repro.

Answer (score 6):

Forcing the compiler to instantiate `tBar::PrintDataAndAddress<tFoo>` before using it solves the problem.

```
int main() 
{
    tBar bar;
    bar.PrintDataAndAddress(tWidget()); // Fine

    auto x = &tBar::PrintDataAndAddress<tFoo>; // <= make it work....

    bar.PrintDataAndAddress(tFoo()); // Now fine

   return 0;
}
```

It seems to be a compiler promlem as it looks quite similar to this:

[In C++, why isn't it possible to friend a template class member function using the template type of another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702433/in-c-why-isnt-it-possible-to-friend-a-template-class-member-function-using-t/39705312#39705312)

To be a little bit more precise... In the line `bar.PrintDataAndAddress(tFoo());` the compiler has to instanciate the memberfunction `tBar::PrintDataAndAddress<tFoo>` and at the same time it has to resolve the friend declaration. That are internaly two seperate steps. Apparent the compiler doesn't do it in the rigth order when written in one expression. To force the compiler to instantiate `bar.PrintDataAndAddress(tFoo())` first by access to the function pointer these two steps are in the right order.

Comment: +1 for finding a workaround. Your theory does not fully explain the behavior we see (like the fact that this is fixed if `tBar` befriends `tFoo` or if `PrintAddress` is not a template function), but is the closest thing we have so far.

Answer (score -3):

Try adding this before the friend function

```
template <typename tFoo>
```

Comment: That does not fix the problem, unfortunately. In fact, it makes it worse, since now all specializations of PrintDataAndAddress will have the same problem, causing both `bar.PrintDataAndAddress(tWidget());` and     `bar.PrintDataAndAddress(tFoo());` to trigger the compilation error (before it would compile fine for the tWidget specialization)

Comment: What type of compiler are you using?

Comment: As stated in the opening question, Clang. You can use an online Clang compiler to test the problem yourself. Click here for a trimmed-down version of the code above provided by @aschepler: rextester.com/YBBQ69572

Comment: It seems that when  void PrintAddress(const T& thing) is made public there is no error using Clang complier

Comment: Well, of course, but the question I am asking is why private members (like PrintAddress) can't be accessed in that context